# SMTP connection using PHP errors

Tags: php, smtp

There is something wrong with:

```
$s = fsockopen($mailserver, 25);
echo '1 > '.fgets($s);
fwrite($s, 'HELO');
echo '2 > '.fgets($s);
fclose($s);
```

Output:

`1 > 220 mail.sogetthis.com ESMTP Postfix 2 >`

Comment: If this isn't a learning exercise, find some library code to use. There is plenty out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `220` code means the SMTP server is ready to accept commands. You're issuing a `HELO` command, and the server should respond with a `250` if your last command was successful, which it is not. Try adding the mailserver domain you're connecting to after your `HELO` command.

```
fwrite($s, "HELO domain.com\r\n");
```

In addition, you should include `\r\n` control characters after all your commands. Notice the double-quotes around the command. That's required to use `\r\n` in this case because double-quotes evaluate variables and control characters.